# How does a convolutional layer convert a 3 channel input into a 1 channel output with 1 kernel?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I will like to know what kind of calculation does a program do to use a kernel to convert a three channel input into one channel. Thank you.